# how to record inbound calls with twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Outbound calls in Twilio can be recorded by setting the TwiML passed to the [client.calls.create()](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-node-js) API method to have a [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) tag with the [record](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#record) attribute set to true. If [recordingStatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-recording-status-callback) is set to a URL it'll post a notification to that URL when the recording is available.

How do you do this for inbound calls?

For my specific phone number, for Voice & Fax, I have, on twilio.com, "Accept Incoming" set to "Voice Calls", "Configure With" set to "TwiML App" and "TwiML App" set to my custom app. For that app I have the Voice Request URL set to a given URL.

When a call is incoming an HTTP POST is made to my TwiML App, which responds with an [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/enqueue). Later, a [Conference Instruction Reservation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/reservations#conference) is made in the client side javascript with [ConferenceRecord](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only) set to true and [ConferenceRecordingStatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only) set to the same URL that we used with `recordingStatusCallback` for the outbound calls.

Here's what my "Conference Instruction Reservation" request payload looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [url] => https://taskrouter.twilio.com/v1/Workspaces/.../Tasks/.../Reservations/...
    [method] => POST
    [token] => ...
    [params] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Instruction] => conference
            [From] =>
            [PostWorkActivitySid] =>
            [Timeout] => 10
            [To] =>
            [EndConferenceOnExit] => true
            [EndConferenceOnCustomerExit] => true
            [ConferenceStatusCallback] => https://my.domain.tld/twilio/conference
            [ConferenceStatusCallbackMethod] => POST
            [ConferenceStatusCallbackEvent] => start,end,join,leave,mute,hold
            [ConferenceRecord] => true
            [ConferenceRecordingStatusCallback] => https://my.domain.tld/twilio/conference/recording
            [ConferenceRecordingStatusCallbackMethod] => POST
            [ConferenceRecordingStatusCallbackEvent] => completed
        )

)
```

As a result of that Twilio calls the `ConferenceStatusCallback` URL multiple times but the `ConferenceRecordingStatusCallback` URL is never called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So idk why the "Conference Instruction Reservation" request approach wasn't working but calling [client.calls.recordings.create()](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#create-a-recording-resource) did the trick